# How to route to sub component in angular

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular app that has parent and sub components structure. I am having issues with navigating to the sub structures.

The main routes are working fine, the issue now is navigating to the sub components.

**This is the sample folder structure for the application.**

[image]

**This is the (notices) main folder routing file**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PublicNoticesPage } from './public-notices.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PublicNoticesPage
  },
  {
    path: 'notices-list',
    loadChildren: () => import('./notices-list/notices-list.module')
.then( m => m.NoticesListPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'notice-categories',
    loadChildren: () => import('./notice-categories/notice-categories.module')
.then( m => m.NoticeCategoriesPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'notice-comments',
    loadChildren: () => import('./notice-comments/notice-comments.module')
.then( m => m.NoticeCommentsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'notices-nearby',
    loadChildren: () => import('./notices-nearby/notices-nearby.module')
.then( m => m.NoticesNearbyPageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PublicNoticesPageRoutingModule {}
```

**This is the root routing file**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module')
.then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/register/register.module')
.then( m => m.RegisterPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot-password',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/forgot-password/forgot-password.module')
.then( m => m.ForgotPasswordPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/home/home.module')
.then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'community',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/community/community.module')
.then( m => m.CommunityPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tourism',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/tourism/tourism.module')
.then( m => m.TourismPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'news',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/news/news.module')
.then( m => m.NewsPageModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'notifications',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/notifications/notifications.module')
.then( m => m.NotificationsPageModule),canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'public-notices',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/public-notices/public-notices.module')
.then( m => m.PublicNoticesPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'deals',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/deals/deals.module')
.then( m => m.DealsPageModule),canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'settings',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/settings/settings.module')
.then( m => m.SettingsPageModule),canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'suggestions',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/suggestions/suggestions.module')
.then( m => m.SuggestionsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'verify-account',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/verify-account/verify-account.module')
.then( m => m.VerifyAccountPageModule),canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

So what I want is to be able to navigate to

Notices -> notices-details ( the sub folder of notices ) and to other files as well.

Comment: The place of the files is of little importance, it only affects the import statements. Your IDE helps with those. Are you getting any errors in the console? What works/what doesn't? Could you maybe create a minimal reproduction in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? I'll gladly take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (notices) main folder routing file should be like this

```
import{NgModule}from'@angular/core';
import{Routes,RouterModule}from'@angular/router';
import{Public Notices Page}from'./public-notices.page';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:PublicNoticesPage, children: [
        {
            path:'notices-list',
            loadChildren:()=>import('./ notices-list/notices-list.module').then(m=>m.NoticesListPageModule)
        },
        {
            path:'notice-categories',
            loadChildren:()=>import('./ notice-categories/notice-categories.module').then(m=>m.NoticeCategories PageModule)
        },
        {
            path:'notice-comments',
            oadChildren()=>import('./ notice-comments/notice-comments.module') .then(m=>n.Notice Comments PageModule)
        },
        {
            path:'notices-nearby',
            loadChildren:()=>import('./ notices-nearby/notices-nearby.module').then(m=>m.Notices NearbyPageModule)
        }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

### Routing and Lazy Loading

Minimal example with lazy loading of a child module:

AppModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'one',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./one/one.module').then((m) => m.OneModule),
      },
    ]),
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

App template:

```html
<button routerLink="one">ONE</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

OneModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([

      {
        path: '', component: OneComponent,
        children: [
          {path: 'two', component: TwoComponent}
        ]
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [OneComponent, TwoComponent]
})
export class OneModule { }
```

One Template:

```html
<p>one works!</p>
<button routerLink="two">TWO</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*You could (but really shouldn't) nest more modules to be lazy loaded. You want to keep your architecture as flat as possible. So a module per feature, lazy loaded from the AppModule, is plenty enough.*

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-94gdzk?file=src/app/one/one.component.html) for you to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Well , I guess I needed a break from the computer. It was just a minor issue on my part.

So What I was doing wrong was not including the parent route segment when browsing to the child component plus the child route was missing a parameter as well.

So it was supposed to be like this .

```
  // View Public Notice Details
  publicNoticeTapped(notice) {
    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      state: {
        articleData: notice,
      },
    };
    this.router.navigate(['public-notices/notice-details', notice.id], navigationExtras);
  }
```

Here is the parent routing module, I was missing :id parameter here as well.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PublicNoticesPage
  },
  {
    path: 'notices-list',
    loadChildren: () => import('./notices-list/notices-list.module')
.then( m => m.NoticesListPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'notice-categories',
    loadChildren: () => import('./notice-categories/notice-categories.module')
.then( m => m.NoticeCategoriesPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'notice-comments',
    loadChildren: () => import('./notice-comments/notice-comments.module')
.then( m => m.NoticeCommentsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'notice-details/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./notice-details/notice-details.module')
.then( m => m.NoticeDetailsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'notices-nearby',
    loadChildren: () => import('./notices-nearby/notices-nearby.module')
.then( m => m.NoticesNearbyPageModule)
  }
];
```

Thanks everyone for your assistance